# Как записать в массив файлы, находящиеся в папке

Tags: c#, массивы, файлы

Итак, у меня есть папка находящаяся по пути **file_path**. Она содержит 188 текстовых файлов.
Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы создать массив **files_array** записать все эти 188 ".txt" файлов в массив и пройтись по нему через цикл.

```cs
string file_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\STALKER SOC\Gamedata\Scripts";

files_array[188]; // Нужный массив содержащий текстовые файлы

for (int i = 0; i < files_array.Length; i++)
{

    files_array[i].ReadToEnd();
    //Проичитать каким-то образом текстовый файл из массива
}
```

Comment: И в чем трудности? Давайте думать логически, есть директория, в ней есть файлы, так? Значит надо обратиться к объекту директории и попросить его отдать все файлы, логично? Вроде да... Директория на англ. будет `Directory`, пишем в студии и да, он показывает, что такой класс есть. Далее получить на англ. будет `Get`, ищем и да, там есть `.GetFiles()`. Ну так в чем тогда трудности? Даже логически можно предположить, не читая документации, что надо делать...

Comment: Хорошо, похоже сработало, я не знал что есть класс Directory, спасибо!

Comment: Научитесь искать самостоятельно. Я вон вам выше описал банальные, логичные действия, которые даже без документации помогут многое решить самостоятельно. Также, что вам мешает написать в любом поисковике `c# get all files`, ну или `c# получить все файлы`, сразу-же получите то, что надо. Экономьте свое время и нервы, ибо сейчас вы потратили как минимум пол часа на то, чтоб спросить незнакомых людей о таком пустяке, который без труда можете найти сами, согласитесь, не очень рациональная трата времени, да? Так что желаю вам научиться самостоятельности, ну и удачи)

Comment: Спасибо, возьму на заметку.

Answer (score 0):

```
string directoryPath = @"C:\lookingfordirectory";
string[] files = Directory.Exists(directoryPath) 
   ? Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.txt") : new string[0];
files.ToList().ForEach(a => WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(a)));
```

Comment: Внесите больше пояснений к вашему ответу

Comment: строка 1 - записать адрес директории,
строка 2 - проверить наличие директории и считать адреса файлов по маске,
строка 3 - вывести список всех файлов, удовлетворяющих условию маски

Comment: не надо в комментарии писать дополнения к ответу, надо редактирвоать ответ, а комментарий удалить.

Answer (score -2):

```cs
FileInfo[] files = Directory
                  .CreateDirectory(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\STALKER SOC\Gamedata\Scripts")
                  .GetFiles(); //Массив текстовых файлов

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
   files[i].OpenText().ReadToEnd(); //Считываем файл и получаем строку
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы создаете новый каталог `CreateDirectory`? Так же, вы получаете экземпляр `StreamReader`, и не закрываете его, это ошибка. Но можно так `string text = File.ReadAllText(files[i].FullPath);`. Кстати, в вашем примере вы читаете текст в никуда.